# How to throw error in async function and handle it only in non-immediate caller?

Tags: javascript, async-await

With regular functions in Javascript, you can have an error thrown way down the call stack and handle it in a non-immediate caller, like this:

```
var a = function () {
    throw new Error ("MyError!!!!");
};
var b = function () {
    a();
};

try {
    b();
} catch (e) {
    console.log ("CAUGHT!!");
}
```

But in async (async/await) functions it seems the error needs to be handled on every step of the way.

If I have some reusable functionality in async function, which needs to throw an error, is there a way to handle the error on a non-immediate caller (like in the example - 2 levels down the call stack instead of 1) so I don't cover with boilerplate the N functions that use it and the M functions that use those N functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in async functions it seems the error needs to be handled on every step of the way.

This is not the case. Just like with Promises, simply `catch` at the level you need to catch the error. `async` functions return `Promises`, after all:

```js
var a = async function () {
    throw new Error ("MyError!!!!");
};
var b = async function () {
    await a();
};
var c = async function () {
    await b();
};

c().catch(e => console.log ("CAUGHT!!"));
```

Comment: OK, I was mistaken, this does seem to work. Thanks. Question: is there a way to have a single catch block on a number of potentially throwing promises? So if you had c(), d() and e() which all can throw and are all async - can you somehow catch on  all of them? What about if you have async and sync function calls in the same block (as it usually is the case) and both async and sync function calls can error out?

Comment: Yes, just continue the pattern - eg  `var c = async function () { await b(); await someOtherFnThatMightThrow(); }; c().catch( ...`

Comment: I see. So basically to catch on all statements I need a function to encapsulate them. Thanks for the answer.